# Android Contacts with Phone Number Only

Tags: android, contacts

I have made an Android app called [Location Texter](https://market.android.com/details?id=couk.chohan.amir.locationtexter.lite).
It works fine apart from when I want to lookup contacts I only want the contacts with phone number to appear. Currently it shows all the contacts.
Here is the code:

```
public  void showContacts(Main main, Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor =  main.managedQuery(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToNext();
    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 

    Cursor phones = main.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);

    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String phoneNo = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        main.numbers.add(phoneNo);
    }
    main.pickPhoneNos(name);
    phones.close();
}
```

What it does is open up an intent with all the contacts. When one of them is selected it goes back to main activity. If the chosen contact has more than one mobile number than it shows a dialogue asking the user to pick one of them. What I have noticed is with some of my attempts that dialogue doesn't appear.
Please download the app if its hard to understand what I am on about.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be more specific with your question, it is hard to understand what you are asking.
I can see a few problems with the code.

1. You never call [moveToFirst()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29) on the `cursor` and `phones` cursor.
2. You are never checking the return value of the first moveToNext() call.

Missing calls to these functions could be making calls further into the method crash.

Comment: I am not surprised about problems with this code. I am not good when it comes to picking contacts.
What my app does is sends a text to the chosen contact. Currently when you press a button (to look up contacts) it shows you ALL the contacts. But I only want it to show contacts that have phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
  hasPhone = "true";
else
  hasPhone = "false" ;

if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
{
  Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" = "+contactId,null, null);
  while (phones.moveToNext()) 
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```